# Recursively display the contents of all the sub-folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have filenames.html.erb file with this in it:

```
<ul style ="list-style-type:none">
    <% for file in @files %>
   <li>
        file name is: <%= file %>
  </li> 
    <% end %>
<ul>
```

I made the neccesary changes to routes.rb and added a `def` method to the controller.

Now, it will list all the files in the current directory, but how can I a write a method that will display the contents of all the sub-folders in the current directory?

Comment: Can you add the method(s) you're using to retrieve the list of files?

Comment: The code to descend through a hierarchy should be in a controller, not a view.

Comment: in the controller i used:  Dir.glob('**/*')  i also return files, all this inside def filenames, for some reason enter 2 asterisks and a "/" then another asterisk wont display in this comment but that is what i put

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy ways in Ruby to display recursive file listings. You'll want to try working with them both and decide which fits your needs better:

Ruby's [Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) class has a good example showing how to recursively descend through a directory hierarchy.

Ruby's [Dir](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html) class can return a list of files as it descends into a folder, but you'll have to parse that list. Dir's [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) will iteratively return files to you, which would be similar to what Find returns. In either case, use a directory name of `**` to signify where you want Ruby to start the deep-dive.

For example, I created a simple set of nested folders like:

```
foo
├── bar
│   └── baz2.txt
└── baz.txt
```

If I `cd` to the "foo" directory and start IRB:

```
>> Dir['./**/*']
[
    [0] "./foo",
    [1] "./foo/bar",
    [2] "./foo/bar/baz2.txt",
    [3] "./foo/baz.txt"
]
```

`Dir['./**/*']` returned an array of paths. `foreach` would return the same list, but only one entry at a time.

Either way, it'll be up to you to decide how to represent that hierarchy. Simply throwing files back to the user could result in a bad user-interface.

Also, you'll need to add the appropriate code to filter out files that should be hidden for whatever reason.

Comment: is there a way to make the display of files on the browser to look more like a tree, for example, your nested folders is perfect for easily identifying which files are in what folder instead of just a plain list.

Comment: Sure. You write code to tell the browser how to render it.